# Server Socket Isn't Sending Data Back in Java

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

So, I just learned how to make `socket`s and all that good stuff in Java, and so my first try got me a message from the client, and then the client crashing. What was supposed to happen was get a message from the client, if that message is equal to this, then send data back. However, the `if` function for if the message was correct wasn't firing, even though the message *was* correct.

Even when I remove the `if` function to check if the string was right or not, the program still freezes up. And by the way, my server is a console application, and my client is a SWT application.

Here's the server code with the removed `if` function:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Waiting for a connection...");
    // Start a server
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3211);
    // Listen for anyone at that port
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    System.out.println("The client has connected!");
    // Get the data being sent in
    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream ouputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    // Turn that into UTF-8
    String data = inputStream.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Received " + data);
    ouputStream.writeUTF("Great!");
    System.out.println("Awesome!");
    socket.close();
    inputStream.close();
    ouputStream.close;
    server.close();
    System.out.println("Socket closed\n-----------------------------");
}
catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

And the client (which is fired when a button gets pressed):

```
try {
    allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\nConnecting to the server...");
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.206", 3211);
    allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\nConnected to the server!");
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    output.writeUTF("sweet");
    String data = input.readUTF();
    allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\nSERVER: " + data);
    input.close();
    output.close();
    socket.close();

}
catch (IOException er) {
    allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\n" + er);
}
```

As soon as I press the button to try and start the connection (with the server already running), the client instantly freezes. It doesn't even send any of the "connecting to server" kind of stuff.

Any idea what's going wrong, and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the server is running on 192.168.1.206?  And are you sure there isn't a firewall preventing access to that port on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your client is reading from `System.in`. It should be reading from the socket input stream.

NB You only need to close the outermost output stream of a socket. That flushes it if necessary and closes the input stream and the socket. You're presently not only closing more than necessary but also in the wrong order,

Answer (score -1):

Your socket is unable to send data because you did not called `.flush()` method on your `outputstream` reference. Use this one and you don't have to write `flush()` and `close()` method explicitely on streams

**Server Code**

```
System.out.println("Waiting for a connection...");
// Start a server
try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3211)) {
    // Listen for anyone at that port
    try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
        System.out.println("The client has connected!");
        // Get the data being sent in
        try (DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))) {
            try (DataOutputStream ouputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                // Turn that into UTF-8
                String data = inputStream.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Received " + data);
                ouputStream.writeUTF("Great!");
                System.out.println("Awesome!");
           }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Socket closed\n-----------------------------");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

**Client Code**

```
try {
    allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\nConnecting to  the server...");
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3211)) {
        allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\nConnected to the server!");
        try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
            try (DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                output.writeUTF("sweet");
            }
            String data = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println(String.format("data received from server '%s':\n", data));
            allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\nSERVER: " +  data);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException er) {
    allMessagesTextBox.setText(allMessagesTextBox.getText() + "\n" + er);
}
```

> **Output on Server**

```
Waiting for a connection...
The client has connected!
Received sweet
Awesome!
Socket closed
-----------------------------
```

> **Output on Client**

```
data received from server 'Great!':
```

Now moving to problem in your code.

See the client side code you have written `DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);` instead of `DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`

which causes the failure in receiving message from server

Comment: This did not solve the problem, the same thing is still happening.

Comment: You have to also `flush` output stream on client side.

Comment: He doesn't have a buffered output stream, so he doesn't need to flush.